# StyleCop 6.1.0 marking as syntax error SA102 C# 6 null-conditional "?." operator

Tags: c#, stylecop

I have StyleCop 6.1.0 running in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.
And StyleCop still marks a as syntax error SA102   legal C# 6  null-conditional  "?."  operator!

Any way to suppress this outdated StyleCop behavior?

Comment: I don't think so. you have to wait for their next update. (uninstalling the extension was my choice a few weeks ago)

Comment: I wish I could avid using StyleCop. Our company requires it. It'll be so much better to use ReSharper only.